# Jenkins pipeline doesn't print full log

Tags: logging, jenkins, makefile, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Makefile:

```
.PHONE: test
REMOVE_IMG_ON_FAIL=true
REMOVE_IMG_WHEN_DONE=true
DOCKER_OPTS = --rm -t
test: test-ubuntu14 test-ubuntu16 test-centos6 test-centos7

test-ubuntu14:
        $(eval ID:=$(shell docker build -f tests/Dockerfile-ubuntu14.04 . | tee /dev/stderr | awk 'END {print $$NF}'))
        docker run ${DOCKER_OPTS} -v ${PWD}/tests/hosts:/etc/hosts ${ID} \
                /ansible-role-this/tests/test.sh || { ${REMOVE_IMG_ON_FAIL} && docker rmi ${ID} && exit 1 ; }
        { ${REMOVE_IMG_WHEN_DONE} && docker rmi ${ID} ; } || true

test-ubuntu16:
        $(eval ID:=$(shell docker build -f tests/Dockerfile-ubuntu16.04 . | tee /dev/stderr | awk 'END {print $$NF}'))
        docker run ${DOCKER_OPTS} -v ${PWD}/tests/hosts:/etc/hosts ${ID} \
                /ansible-role-this/tests/test.sh || { ${REMOVE_IMG_ON_FAIL} && docker rmi ${ID} && exit 1 ; }
        { ${REMOVE_IMG_WHEN_DONE} && docker rmi ${ID} ; } || true

test-centos6:
        $(eval ID:=$(shell docker build -f tests/Dockerfile-centos6 . | tee /dev/stderr | awk 'END {print $$NF}'))
        docker run ${DOCKER_OPTS} -v ${PWD}/tests/hosts:/etc/hosts ${ID} \
                /ansible-role-this/tests/test.sh || { ${REMOVE_IMG_ON_FAIL} && docker rmi ${ID} && exit 1 ; }
        { ${REMOVE_IMG_WHEN_DONE} && docker rmi ${ID} ; } || true

test-centos7:
        $(eval ID:=$(shell docker build -f tests/Dockerfile-centos7 . | tee /dev/stderr | awk 'END {print $$NF}'))
        docker run ${DOCKER_OPTS} -v ${PWD}/tests/hosts:/etc/hosts ${ID} \
                /ansible-role-this/tests/test.sh || { ${REMOVE_IMG_ON_FAIL} && docker rmi ${ID} && exit 1 ; }
        { ${REMOVE_IMG_WHEN_DONE} && docker rmi ${ID} ; } || true
```

along with Jenkinsfile

```
node {
  stage 'Checkout'
  checkout scm

  stage 'test'
  catchError {
    wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm']) {
      sh 'make test'
    }
  }
  step([$class: 'Mailer',
       notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
       recipients: emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
                                       [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']])])
}
```

It works fine, but for some reason pipeline prints only the first **test-ubuntu14** output, but doesn't print the rest. Though they are definitely executed. unfortunately this complicates the debugging process.

**UPDATE**: As a workaround I used this Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
  stage 'Checkout'
  checkout scm

  stage 'test'
  catchError {
    wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm']) {
      sh 'make test-ubuntu14'
      sh 'make test-ubuntu16'
      sh 'make test-centos6'
      sh 'make test-centos7'
    }
  }
  step([$class: 'Mailer',
       notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
       recipients: emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
                                       [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']])])
}
```

Anyway, I still want to know how to print output of the single make test.

Answer (score 1):

try getting the output into a variable:
result = sh script: 'make test-ubuntu14', returnStdout: true

the just print the variable 
print result